# JPA find entities with given list of tags

Tags: jpa, playframework

I have Tag object and Price object with list of tags. I'm able to find Price with one specified tag, but I don't know how to write query to find Price with given list of tags like: find price where price.tags=blue,red,green. The result must have all tags named blue, red and green.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Tag extends Model implements Comparable<Tag>{

    public String name;

    public Tag(){
    }

    public Tag(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Tag findOrCreateByName(String name) {
        Tag tag = Tag.find("byName", name).first();
        if(tag == null) {
            tag = new Tag(name);
        }
        return tag;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tag otherTag) {
        return name.compareTo(otherTag.name);
    }
  }

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Price extends Model{

    @Min(0.0)
    public float price;

    @ManyToMany
    public List<Tag> tags;

    public Price() {
        this.tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    }

    public Price(int price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.tags = new ArrayList<Tag>();
    }

    public Price tagItWith(String name) {
        tags.add(Tag.findOrCreateByName(name));
        return this;
    }

    public static List<Price> findTaggedWith(String tag) {
        return Price.find(
                "select distinct p from Price p join p.tags as t where t.name = ?", tag
        ).fetch();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the other side of the relationship in Tag.
You will also need to user mappedby in Proce @ManyToMany in order to define the "master" of the relationship.

See example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/Kkt1uYVJK5k)